# Elastic nodes goes down as gc kicks in

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, jvm

ES Version: 5.4.1
OS: Ubuntu
Java:1.8

#### Issue

We currently upgraded our systems from es 2.3 to es5.4.1, everything was going well till we deployed it on production. It started with es node going for some time randomly. On  investigation, we saw under logs in es

```
[2017-12-15T20:33:28,459][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][1723] overhead, spent [252ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T20:42:53,599][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][2288] overhead, spent [288ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T20:53:55,846][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][2950] overhead, spent [313ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:03:18,145][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][3512] overhead, spent [325ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:45:45,815][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6059] overhead, spent [340ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:46:39,834][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6113] overhead, spent [445ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:46:59,895][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6133] overhead, spent [281ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:47:27,901][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6161] overhead, spent [306ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:51:56,093][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6429] overhead, spent [297ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2017-12-15T21:51:57,094][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6430] overhead, spent [353ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:57:56,361][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6789] overhead, spent [398ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2017-12-15T21:58:23,407][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6816] overhead, spent [284ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T21:58:24,444][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][6817] overhead, spent [341ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T22:01:29,536][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7002] overhead, spent [341ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T22:01:31,663][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7004] overhead, spent [399ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2017-12-15T22:01:35,664][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7008] overhead, spent [273ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T22:03:08,779][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7101] overhead, spent [281ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T22:05:54,928][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7267] overhead, spent [310ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2017-12-15T22:05:55,928][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7268] overhead, spent [305ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-12-15T22:05:58,929][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [vzvV7bX] [gc][7271] overhead, spent [287ms] collecting in the last [1s]
```

```
Earlier the ES 2.3 used to work with 8gb memory on the system with 32 GB ram. We increased the heap space from 8 to 12 and then we increased system ram to 64 GB and give 32 GB heap to elastic search but the es nodes keep going down when there is any heavy query. Please note that earlier everything was working fine.

For 12 GB the details are as under

```
  "jvm" : {
        "timestamp" : 1513422077508,
        "uptime_in_millis" : 16750330,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_used_in_bytes" : 9402202880,
          "heap_used_percent" : 73,
          "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 12815171584,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 12815171584,
          "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 97693480,
          "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 103424000,
          "pools" : {
            "young" : {
              "used_in_bytes" : 441150480,
              "max_in_bytes" : 558432256,
              "peak_used_in_bytes" : 558432256,
              "peak_max_in_bytes" : 558432256
            },
            "survivor" : {
              "used_in_bytes" : 42550952,
              "max_in_bytes" : 69730304,
              "peak_used_in_bytes" : 69730304,
              "peak_max_in_bytes" : 69730304
            },
            "old" : {
              "used_in_bytes" : 8918501448,
              "max_in_bytes" : 12187009024,
              "peak_used_in_bytes" : 8918501448,
              "peak_max_in_bytes" : 12187009024
            }
          }
        },
        "threads" : {
          "count" : 71,
          "peak_count" : 95
        },
        "gc" : {
          "collectors" : {
            "young" : {
              "collection_count" : 104,
              "collection_time_in_millis" : 7078
            },
            "old" : {
              "collection_count" : 1,
              "collection_time_in_millis" : 170
            }
          }
        },
        "buffer_pools" : {
          "direct" : {
            "count" : 67,
            "used_in_bytes" : 847203522,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 847203521
          },
          "mapped" : {
            "count" : 1204,
            "used_in_bytes" : 16787345787,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 16787345787
          }
        },
        "classes" : {
          "current_loaded_count" : 11025,
          "total_loaded_count" : 11025,
          "total_unloaded_count" : 0
        } 
      }
    }
```

```

But till right now we are not able to find any concrete soln to the problem

Created a [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27872) in Github but was closed, so created a [topic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-nodes-goes-down-as-gc-kicks-in/112337) on forum here

Now we compared the es queries that were fired against es2.3 and es5.4

for es2.3 query was like

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 200,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ 

           {
            "bool" : {
              "must_not" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "should" : {
                    "terms" : {
                      "room_id" : [ 

                        -- terms upto 30000 -

                       ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          } 
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter" : {

          -- basic filter --

      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : [ 

    -- columns -- 

  ],
  "sort" : [
    -- columns --
  ]
}
```

and  query for 5.4 is

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 20,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
             {
                "bool" : {
                  "must_not" : [
                    {
                      "bool" : {
                        "should" : [
                          {
                            "terms" : {
                              "room_ids" : [

                               -- terms can upto be 30000 --

                              ],
                              "boost" : 1.0
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "disable_coord" : false,
                        "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "disable_coord" : false,
                  "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
      ],
      "filter" : [

            -- some basic filters --

      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "_source" : {
    "includes" : [

        --columns--

    ],
    "excludes" : [ ]
  },
  "sort" : [

    --columns--

  ]
}
```

The main difference is in 2.3 we are getting data from `fields` and in 5.4 we are doing from `_source`, everything else is almost same, but for 2.3 everything seems to be working fine.

Someone suggested me that heap size is too large [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-nodes-goes-down-as-gc-kicks-in/112337). S bo I set java Xms to 8GB but still nodes are going down

```
  {
    "_nodes" : {
      "total" : 1,
      "successful" : 1,
      "failed" : 0
    },
    "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_cc",
    "nodes" : {
      "vzvV7bXVQd-9aVzF_CrcHA" : {
        "timestamp" : 1513839849278,
        "name" : "vzvV7bX",
        "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
        "host" : "127.0.0.1",
        "ip" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
        "roles" : [
          "master",
          "data",
          "ingest"
        ],
        "indices" : {
          "docs" : {
            "count" : 10490979,
            "deleted" : 759806
          },
          "store" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 12759778301,
            "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "indexing" : {
            "index_total" : 86,
            "index_time_in_millis" : 738,
            "index_current" : 0,
            "index_failed" : 0,
            "delete_total" : 0,
            "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "delete_current" : 0,
            "noop_update_total" : 40,
            "is_throttled" : false,
            "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "get" : {
            "total" : 75,
            "time_in_millis" : 27,
            "exists_total" : 75,
            "exists_time_in_millis" : 27,
            "missing_total" : 0,
            "missing_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "current" : 0
          },
          "search" : {
            "open_contexts" : 0,
            "query_total" : 5292,
            "query_time_in_millis" : 31440,
            "query_current" : 0,
            "fetch_total" : 3325,
            "fetch_time_in_millis" : 117815,
            "fetch_current" : 0,
            "scroll_total" : 0,
            "scroll_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "scroll_current" : 0,
            "suggest_total" : 0,
            "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "suggest_current" : 0
          },
          "merges" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "current_docs" : 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "total" : 6,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 2203,
            "total_docs" : 2303,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 8707990,
            "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 671088640
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "total" : 154,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 1763,
            "listeners" : 0
          },
          "flush" : {
            "total" : 57,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 830
          },
          "warmer" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "total" : 218,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 413
          },
          "query_cache" : {
            "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1807608,
            "total_count" : 22863,
            "hit_count" : 2962,
            "miss_count" : 19901,
            "cache_size" : 836,
            "cache_count" : 836,
            "evictions" : 0
          },
          "fielddata" : {
            "memory_size_in_bytes" : 2112304,
            "evictions" : 0
          },
          "completion" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 0
          },
          "segments" : {
            "count" : 490,
            "memory_in_bytes" : 54231303,
            "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 40778050,
            "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 3325704,
            "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
            "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 637056,
            "points_memory_in_bytes" : 580557,
            "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 8909936,
            "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
            "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
            "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 1199712,
            "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
            "file_sizes" : { }
          },
          "translog" : {
            "operations" : 3,
            "size_in_bytes" : 18452
          },
          "request_cache" : {
            "memory_size_in_bytes" : 66679,
            "evictions" : 0,
            "hit_count" : 84,
            "miss_count" : 130
          },
          "recovery" : {
            "current_as_source" : 0,
            "current_as_target" : 0,
            "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
          }
        },
        "os" : {
          "timestamp" : 1513839849384,
          "cpu" : {
            "percent" : 3,
            "load_average" : {
              "1m" : 0.05,
              "5m" : 0.38,
              "15m" : 1.06
            }
          },
          "mem" : {
            "total_in_bytes" : 33738969088,
            "free_in_bytes" : 15510724608,
            "used_in_bytes" : 18228244480,
            "free_percent" : 46,
            "used_percent" : 54
          },
          "swap" : {
            "total_in_bytes" : 0,
            "free_in_bytes" : 0,
            "used_in_bytes" : 0
          }
        },
        "process" : {
          "timestamp" : 1513839849384,
          "open_file_descriptors" : 344,
          "max_file_descriptors" : 65536,
          "cpu" : {
            "percent" : 0,
            "total_in_millis" : 329250
          },
          "mem" : {
            "total_virtual_in_bytes" : 28131942400
          }
        },
        "jvm" : {
          "timestamp" : 1513839849384,
          "uptime_in_millis" : 12440740,
          "mem" : {
            "heap_used_in_bytes" : 2964483576,
            "heap_used_percent" : 34,
            "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 6240751616,
            "heap_max_in_bytes" : 8520204288,
            "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 102879720,
            "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 108969984,
            "pools" : {
              "young" : {
                "used_in_bytes" : 451090984,
                "max_in_bytes" : 558432256,
                "peak_used_in_bytes" : 558432256,
                "peak_max_in_bytes" : 558432256
              },
              "survivor" : {
                "used_in_bytes" : 16900480,
                "max_in_bytes" : 69730304,
                "peak_used_in_bytes" : 69730304,
                "peak_max_in_bytes" : 69730304
              },
              "old" : {
                "used_in_bytes" : 2496492112,
                "max_in_bytes" : 7892041728,
                "peak_used_in_bytes" : 5608349440,
                "peak_max_in_bytes" : 7892041728
              }
            }
          },
          "threads" : {
            "count" : 88,
            "peak_count" : 99
          },
          "gc" : {
            "collectors" : {
              "young" : {
                "collection_count" : 86,
                "collection_time_in_millis" : 14592
              },
              "old" : {
                "collection_count" : 11,
                "collection_time_in_millis" : 780
              }
            }
          },
          "buffer_pools" : {
            "direct" : {
              "count" : 57,
              "used_in_bytes" : 795161001,
              "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 795161000
            },
            "mapped" : {
              "count" : 1080,
              "used_in_bytes" : 12730171248,
              "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 12730171248
            }
          },
          "classes" : {
            "current_loaded_count" : 11264,
            "total_loaded_count" : 11388,
            "total_unloaded_count" : 124
          }
        },
        "thread_pool" : {
          "bulk" : {
            "threads" : 5,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 5,
            "completed" : 84
          },
          "fetch_shard_started" : {
            "threads" : 1,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 16,
            "completed" : 35
          },
          "fetch_shard_store" : {
            "threads" : 0,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 0,
            "completed" : 0
          },
          "flush" : {
            "threads" : 1,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 4,
            "completed" : 114
          },
          "force_merge" : {
            "threads" : 0,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 0,
            "completed" : 0
          },
          "generic" : {
            "threads" : 4,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 4,
            "completed" : 1286
          },
          "get" : {
            "threads" : 0,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 0,
            "completed" : 0
          },
          "index" : {
            "threads" : 8,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 8,
            "completed" : 75
          },
          "listener" : {
            "threads" : 0,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 0,
            "completed" : 0
          },
          "management" : {
            "threads" : 4,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 1,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 4,
            "completed" : 1653
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "threads" : 4,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 4,
            "completed" : 86950
          },
          "search" : {
            "threads" : 13,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 13,
            "completed" : 13533
          },
          "snapshot" : {
            "threads" : 0,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 0,
            "completed" : 0
          },
          "warmer" : {
            "threads" : 4,
            "queue" : 0,
            "active" : 0,
            "rejected" : 0,
            "largest" : 4,
            "completed" : 1362
          }
        },
        "fs" : {
          "timestamp" : 1513839849386,
          "total" : {
            "total_in_bytes" : 42141548544,
            "free_in_bytes" : 21673201664,
            "available_in_bytes" : 19508940800
          },
          "data" : [
            {
              "path" : "/data/elasticsearch_cc/nodes/0",
              "mount" : "/data (/dev/xvdf)",
              "type" : "ext4",
              "total_in_bytes" : 42141548544,
              "free_in_bytes" : 21673201664,
              "available_in_bytes" : 19508940800,
              "spins" : "false"
            }
          ],
          "io_stats" : {
            "devices" : [
              {
                "device_name" : "xvdf",
                "operations" : 32559,
                "read_operations" : 29633,
                "write_operations" : 2926,
                "read_kilobytes" : 1682476,
                "write_kilobytes" : 51428
              }
            ],
            "total" : {
              "operations" : 32559,
              "read_operations" : 29633,
              "write_operations" : 2926,
              "read_kilobytes" : 1682476,
              "write_kilobytes" : 51428
            }
          }
        },
        "transport" : {
          "server_open" : 26,
          "rx_count" : 10895,
          "rx_size_in_bytes" : 1251104,
          "tx_count" : 10893,
          "tx_size_in_bytes" : 12114262496
        },
        "http" : {
          "current_open" : 1,
          "total_opened" : 1
        },
        "breakers" : {
          "request" : {
            "limit_size_in_bytes" : 5112122572,
            "limit_size" : "4.7gb",
            "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "estimated_size" : "0b",
            "overhead" : 1.0,
            "tripped" : 0
          },
          "fielddata" : {
            "limit_size_in_bytes" : 5112122572,
            "limit_size" : "4.7gb",
            "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 2112304,
            "estimated_size" : "2mb",
            "overhead" : 1.03,
            "tripped" : 0
          },
          "in_flight_requests" : {
            "limit_size_in_bytes" : 8520204288,
            "limit_size" : "7.9gb",
            "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 3206,
            "estimated_size" : "3.1kb",
            "overhead" : 1.0,
            "tripped" : 0
          },
          "parent" : {
            "limit_size_in_bytes" : 5964143001,
            "limit_size" : "5.5gb",
            "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 2115510,
            "estimated_size" : "2mb",
            "overhead" : 1.0,
            "tripped" : 0
          }
        },
        "script" : {
          "compilations" : 0,
          "cache_evictions" : 0
        },
        "discovery" : {
          "cluster_state_queue" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "pending" : 0,
            "committed" : 0
          }
        },
        "ingest" : {
          "total" : {
            "count" : 0,
            "time_in_millis" : 0,
            "current" : 0,
            "failed" : 0
          },
          "pipelines" : { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```